# Negative lookback to see if previous character from a \n is Y

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to match every new line that is not preceded by a `Y` and replace it with an empty string, but this expression is giving me an error.

```
$tsv = preg_replace("/(?<!Y)\n/m", "", $tsv);
```

But that is for some reason replacing all line breaks. What is wrong with my lookback?

Comment: You could remove the m-modifier. Beware that when you replace the single newline, this `Y\n\n\n\nY\n\n\n` turns into this `Y\n\n\nY\n\n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be dealing with a file that has a different line-ending than you expected.

- `\r` - usually used on Mac-based systems
- `\n` - usually used on Unix-based systems
- `\r\n` - usually used on Windows-based systems

You could try this to handle any line ending:

```
$tsv = preg_replace("/(?<!Y)(\r\n?|\n)/m", "", $tsv);
```

Comment: Yeah, it was `\r\n`. Thanks so much!